# overlapped results in tables for research journal

Tags: journals, writing

In research papers (for examples, computer science journals), may I have overlaps between multiple tables containing experiment results?

My situation is like this. I have two tables Table A and Table B in the experiment section. Table A contains performance results from model-a,b,c. Table B contains performance results from model-c,d,e.

Thus, the two tables has an overlap as both contain the same reulst of model-c.

Each table highlihgts a distinct point. That is, each table is made to verify a different claim.

If I simply combine them into one table that shows all results of model-a,b,c,d,e, it will seriously degrade readability and make the points unclear.

So I am wondering if it is okay to contain overlap in diferent result tables.

Comment: What you write is probably fine, but ultimately it depends on the journal how much duplication they will allow.

Comment: @jachilles You seem to be thinking about the potential readers, which is fantastic.

Comment: If you think this should be closed for "individual factors" please give an example where it would not be okay.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there is no rule against that. Just make it clear to the reader that some of the data is the same as in the other table.

The main disadvantage is that you are increasing the length by duplicating content, but if not doing so seriously degrades the readability as you say, then I don't think it would be an obstacle.

Comment: Being a table column , it does not even makes the paper longer, at least not in a linear way. What will make the paper longer is OP saying something about the different use of the same column. Plus 1.